# Some way to evaluate and explain python expression (a la pytest)

Tags: python, pytest

I'm looking for some approach or tool that can evaluate python expression like `eval()` does, but with additional resolving of the variables like in pytest when assertion leads to False.
Something like this:

```
globals_ = {'a': 10, 'b': 7, 'multiply_by_2': lambda x: x * 2}
result = smart_eval('4 == multiply_by_2(a - b)', globals_)
print(result.result, result.explanation, sep='\n')

# False
#  4 == 6
#  +  where 6 = multiply_by_2((10 - 7))
```

Of course the evaluated expression may be much more complex and contain multiple nested function calls

Maybe this functionality somehow can be taken from **pytest**

As described in the pytest docs, it only can be executed against some file (you need to specify filename or dirname when calling `pytest.main()`. So if there is a way to run pytest against a string containing python code, it will solve my task.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych it's absolutely not about preferred tools and opinions. I'm searching for a way to accomplish my exact programming task described in the question.

Comment: Your first sentence says otherwise… if you have a specific framework in mind that’s allowed, eg “how to use pytest as an interactive static code analysis engine” to which I expect the answer will be “you can’t”.

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Eval](https://pypi.org/project/simpleeval/) looks like exactly what you are looking for. You can define specific functions, operand behavior, and variable names.

See a couple of examples from its docs:

```
>>> simple_eval("square(11)", functions={"square": lambda x: x*x})
121
>>> simple_eval("'equal' if x == y else 'not equal'",
                names={"x": 1, "y": 2})
'not equal'
```

Comment: It's not what I want (get a step by step explanation) out of the box, but it's a good starting point to make it by myself, thanks!